# Can a thread be interrupted by the scheduler just before it returns?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, scheduling

I've got two threads working as producer, consumer. In the producer thread I've got the following code:

```
{
    mediaQueue->PushEvent( boost::bind(/* params are not important */) );

    return 0;
}
```

mediaQueue is a message queue and on a PushEvent() call a thread is notified that there is a job to be processed. The consumer thread just executes the functor, created with bind.

For me it's really important that the producer thread returns BEFORE the consumer thread executes the functor.

So the question: **Is it possible the producer to be interrupted just after it pushes the event but before it returns?**

My research so far makes me think that **it is possible and I should implement locking**, but what's your opinion on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheduler can interrupt your thread at any time. It doesn't (necessarily) know or care what your thread is doing when its time is up. If there's a possible race condition, yes, you must take the time and effort to implement correct locking.

In your case, it's easy enough. Just wait on an object that's set in the callee function on return from your `PushEvent` function.

Comment: Yeah - this is strange requirement.  Using a synchro object to force the return of the producer before the consumer gets to the main body of its code will surely work, as you say, but is highly likely to result in a near-pointless context change as the consumer wakes up on the queue and then blocks again on the explicit synchro wait:(  Still, best, (only?) solution to an unreasonable request, so +1.

Comment: @MartinJames: there's a rule of thumb for that, though. If the current (broken) code without synchronization appears to work, then the threads are currently executing in the "correct" order by chance. So the synchronization will be cheap, because the synchro object will be released before it needs to be acquired in the other thread. Exchanging a chance of UB when the timings change, for a chance of a double context switch when the timings change, is a great deal :-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop yes, that's exactly my point. The code works that way but I'm sure it'll cause problems as soon as it gets on production :)

Comment: The protocol/library is borked.  Waiting in the consumer until the producer callback signals will not help much and may even make things worse.  Just because the callback signals does not mean that it has sent the '0,1,3' reply.  Threads that are waiting on a synchro object are given a priority boost when they are made ready and so the newly-ready consumer may preempt the producer upon the signal call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. A thread can be descheduled pretty much any time.

It sounds like there's something wrong though, if it matters when the statement `return 0;` is executed. Is it really the *return* that has to execute before the functor, or is it something else that the producer thread does?

Comment: Yes, it's a design issue but unfortunately beyond my control. It works that way
1. Client sends requests and waits for synchronous confirmation that it's accepted
2. Server accepts the call (via callback) and returns 0 or 1
3. The client waits for async response about the result.
The problem here is that if the 2nd thread starts before the return I may send result for a job which is not yet confirmed as accepted.

Comment: Sounds like it's the conformation of acceptance that the consumer thread needs to wait for, rather than the return in the code you show.

Comment: @tsurko - don't understand. Why do you not just send the accept before queueing the job to the 2nd thread?

Comment: The code above is called by the communication library. If I return I won't be able to add the job to the queue. That's why I add the job and then return.

Comment: This code is called as a callback - the return code is what the function returns. I can't put it in the 2nd thread.
The point is that it's expected that the 2nd thread will do some work before sending result, but as it always happens - this is not true for all cases.

Comment: You're pretty well stuft then.  It's not the return from the queue push that matters, it's when the comms library decides to send the return from your callback and so commits the 0,1 or 3 to the TCP stack. Unless the library provides another event to signal that the send is complete, I can't see how you can do anything in a reliable manner.  Signalling the consumer from the callback dosn't help since the consumer may still send its result before the comms library sends the accept.

Comment: The only band-aid bodge I can see off-hand is to raise the priority of the producer to try and ensure that it runs to the '0,1,3' send before the consumer is ready to send its results.  It's another contribution to scrapheap software but it may be the only way short of fixing the library, (alternative: lowering priority of consumer - same thing).

Comment: That's true. And unfortunately you are absolutely right that I can't do much about this...